# What does this mean "!somePointer"?

Tags: c++, pointers

So reading some code, and there is a syntax I don't understand.

The code is like this

```
int * aPtr = new int();
if(!aPtr)               // this part I don't understand
{
 //some code here
}
```

I'm guessing the syntax is asking whether the pointer is pointing to null, but
in most of the books I read, usually are stated like this

```
if(aPtr == NULL)
{

}
```

Comment: Note that `aPtr` will never be null here, so the `if` will never be entered. `new` does not return null.

Comment: Thanks guys! Just wanted to double check.

Comment: To make this convention easier to read, think of it as saying `if (not valid pointer)`.

Comment: To make this code meaningful using standard C++ you would have to use `int* aPtr = new(std::nothrow) int();`. This overload returns `NULL` on failure instead of throwing a `std::bad_alloc`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There're three important points in your question

### 1. Is it null ?

A null pointer evaluates to zero:

> A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19)
>   prvalue of integer type that evaluates to **zero** ... (§ 4.10 /1)

So to check if a pointer is null or not, you can check it against **zero**.
Traditional way (legacy from C) to check a variable against zero is

```
if (!var)  // if (var == 0)
```

---

### 2. What is macro `NULL`?

It is an integral constant expression which evaluates to zero, but.. forget using `NULL`, use `0` or `nullptr` instead. For more information read [*"Should I use NULL or 0?"*](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#null)

---

### 3. How to check `new` failed or not?

> ... it is called by a placement
>   version of a new-expression when a C++ program prefers a null pointer
>   result as an error indication, instead of a bad_alloc exception.
>   (18.6.1.1 / 5)

```
int *aPtr = new int();
if(!aPtr)
```

It seems you want to check whether `new` succeeded or failed. It's wrong, because if it fails it throws an exception and the program will not reach to the `if (!aPtr)`. Therefore, you should handle it by `try/catch`.

Also, you can force compiler to stop throwing exception and return null instead. For this, you should try:

```
int* aPtr = new(std::nothrow) int();
```

Answer (score 2):

`aptr` will be non-zero if it is something other than `nullptr`. It's basically a shorter way of saying:

```
if (aptr == nullptr)
```

Comment: No, it's non-zero if it *is* something other than `nullptr`. (And it's no quicker to execute, just quicker to type and IMHO slightly more difficult to read.)

Comment: @KeithThompson Right but I don't recall saying it's quicker to execute... o.O

Comment: It is the *opposite* of what you have stated.  `if ( ! ptr )` is equivalent to `if ( ptr == NULL )`

Comment: @HappyGreenKidNaps Yeah forgot to change that one.

Answer (score 1):

! is for logical NOT operator. when attached to a pointer, it returns true if the pointer is null.

Answer (score 1):

operator `!` negates its argument

NULL value in most c++ compilers/libraries is defined as integer zero (0), which is not quite right, but anyway

so operator ! negates integer value, and if this value is 0 (ie pointer is NULL) - then we have `true`

but in general case - it is bad practice to depend on this, you should compare with nullptr

UPDATE: as per comments and standard - you can expect that NULL is evaluated as 0, so you can safely use `if (pointer)` or `if (!pointer)`, but I personally prefer to compare it with proper consts, as it then clearly seen that it is pointer and not just integral value

Comment: `NULL` is defined to be an integral constant expression that evaluates to zero. This is standard C++, so **all** C++ compilers implement it this way.

Comment: @IInspectable it is philosophy, as pointer to 0 address is valid pointer in some systems, this is why I don't like that NULL=0

Comment: This is not about what you like or what you dislike or what some systems allow. It is a rule with little leeway. A C++ compiler is well advised following the rules. Besides, `NULL` is not necessarily `0` - it is implementation defined, and `0L` is explicitly spelled out as an alternative in the standard.

Comment: @IInspectable In C++11, `NULL` could also be defined as `nullptr`. `NULL` is specified as a null pointer constant, which is either of integral or `nullptr_t` type.

Comment: @IInspectable if we go that way: standard says that null pointer should be evaluated as 0, but not defined as 0, some compilers can define NULL as non 0, but still evaluate it as 0

Comment: @Ilya I guess that's what I stated in my first comment, no?

Comment: @DyP True. I still live in past-decade-C++-land. Thanks for the additional information.

Comment: @IInspectable sophistic began :) I prefer to say: different compilers `implements` this differently, but all these implementations provide similar results during `evaluation` of NULL value